# Differential equation of all non horizontal lines?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know this a repeated question but i have some doubts to clarify .

**Attempts**

$\frac{dy}{dx}=(a$ $constant$ $say)=m$ and $m\neq 0$

Hence we have $\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}=0$

*Also*

Consider general equation of line
$ax+by+c=0$

$a\frac{dx}{dy}+b=0$

$a\frac{d^{2}x}{dy^{2}}=0$

Since $a\neq 0$ therefore we have $\frac{d^{2}x}{dy^{2}}=0$

Is my method legitimate ? Is $\frac{d^{2}x}{dy^{2}}=0$ , $\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}=0$ the correct answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there exists a a unique case where $\frac{dy}{dx}=\infty$ ie : not defined there will also be a case of $\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}=\infty$ so only one of those are possible.

Hence differential equation of all non horizontal lines is $\frac{d^{2}x}{dy^{2}}=0$ only.