# Find the differential equation of all non-horizontal lines in a plane.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the differential equation of all non-horizontal lines in a plane.

---

This question is also present [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1465840/differential-equation-of-all-non-horizontal-lines,). But I do not understand that solution.
Let $y=mx+c,m\ne0$ be the equation of all non-horizontal lines in a plane.
As it has two arbitrary constants $m$ and $c$,we need to differentiate it two times.
$y=mx+c$
$\frac{dy}{dx}=m$
$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$
But my book says answer is $\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}=0$.
Book gives this solution.
Let $ax+by+c=0,a\ne0$ be the equation of all non-horizontal lines in a plane.
Differentiating both sides wrt $y$,

$a\frac{dx}{dy}+b=0$
$a\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}=0$
As $a\ne0,\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}=0$
My answer and book answer are completely different.I do not understand what is wrong in my answer?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

Non-horizontal means that it can be **oblique** or **vertical**. Does your solution contains vertical lines $x=\text{Constant}$?

Comment: It should contain. Non-horizontal means every line in the xy-plane except y=constant.

Comment: @ReeshabhRanjan: Hi. :) Does your statement differ with what I said? :) I think you said the same thing as I said in a different way! :)

Answer (score 0):

This came in one of my recent exams in school. Our teacher said that if we differentiate with respect to x, then the first differential will give f'(x)=m. In this case, though m≠0, but  m can attain the value ∞. But if we differentiate wrt y that is dx/dy, we get it to be equal to 1/m. Now in the second case, 1/m is restricted to attain ∞ as m≠0. 
It may attain 0 though. But the case of ∞ is adjusted in a better way.
I still don't understand what's the need of it, but seems a bit convincing.
Anyways I wrote d2y/dx2=0 as the answer, which is wrong.